# Paste text into linux terminal takes so long?

Tags: linux, terminal

It takes a lot of time just paste text into the terminal, it appears character by character, I'm wondering what's the reason to this behavior, cpu, ram or anything else?

Comment: I guess you're 'pasting' long text into terminal of remote host. If so - that's a network overhead matter.

Comment: no, local host, that's why I think it's strange.

Comment: Some terminals use linear-time layout algorithms which fire on every character inserted (this is quite common), resulting in quadratic slow-downs (especially if a lot of text is inserted). If you're pasting only a few characters and it still pastes only character by character, try switching terminal emulators.

Comment: Yes, like what you said, it slows down as it pastes. At first, it was quick. Thank you. @nneonneo

Comment: The only advice I can really give is to try switching terminal emulators. You could always file a bug with the developers of your terminal emulator, but the behaviour is likely by-design (e.g. there's no way to get the layout they want without their algorithm)

Comment: does anyone know how to find and kill this process if it takes too long? I am pasting a very long text now and it is still typing and won't stop with Ctrl+C.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/